# Spring boot app getting "Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession'"

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-astra

I'm experiencing some troubles with Apache Cassandra and I think you could help me out!
So, this is my pom

```
<groupId>com.inboxapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>inbox-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>inbox-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.prettytime</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettytime</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

These are my classes:

```
@Table(value = "folders_by_user")
public class Folder {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "user_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String id;

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "label", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    private String label;

    // @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "created_time_uuid", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED, ordering = Ordering.ASCENDING)
    // @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    // private UUID createdTimeUuid;

    @CassandraType(type = CassandraType.Name.TEXT)
    private String color;

    @Transient
    private int unreadCount;
```

The config class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datastax.astra")
public class DataStaxAstraProperties {

    private File secureConnectBundle;

    public File getSecureConnectBundle() {
        return secureConnectBundle;
    }

    public void setSecureConnectBundle(File secureConnectBundle) {
        this.secureConnectBundle = secureConnectBundle;
    }
}
```

And the main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringGitHubLoginApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringGitHubLoginApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer sessionBuilderCustomizer(DataStaxAstraProperties astraProperties) {
        Path bundle = astraProperties.getSecureConnectBundle().toPath();
        return builder -> builder.withCloudSecureConnectBundle(bundle);
    }

}
```

There's soomething missing that I'm not seeing or what? As far as I can see there's no annotation missing. I've to say that I've done also the repository (not included here).
Thanks in adnvace!

Comment: what is the full stacktrace ?